# Backbone dummy: understanding collection synchronization

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I want to synchronise my collection each time an item is added.

So if user adds an item in another browser window - the server still sends us valid data.

And so... I got stuck! I read the docs a couple of times, but still can't undersand:

- which method sends the data to server?
- which method parses items from server's response and puts them into the collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- which method sends the data to server?

[model.save([attributes], [options])](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save) :

> Save a model to your database (or alternative persistence layer), by
>   delegating to Backbone.sync.

- which method parses items from server's response and puts them into the collection?

[model.parse(response)](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-parse)  or [collection.parse(response)](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse):

> parse is called whenever a model's data is returned by the server, in
>   fetch, and save. The function is passed the raw response object, and
>   should return the attributes hash to be set on the model. The default
>   implementation is a no-op, simply passing through the JSON response.
>   Override this if you need to work with a preexisting API, or better
>   namespace your responses.